# Splitting power to two devices (Raspberry Pi & LED Matrix)

Tags: power-supply, current, voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi, led-matrix

I am working on a small project involving a Raspberry Pi and an LED matrix.

Both devices are rated for 5V but requiring different current (approximately 2A for the Pi and 4A for the LED matrix).

Basically I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7Zrnr4kGw8&t=186s

except that I only have one LED panel, whereas he has two.

I would like to only have **one** power supply for both devices.
Could this be achieved by simply splitting the output from a 5V 6A power supply, say, to both devices?

Assuming that I have enough current for both devices, are there any other issues that could arise from connecting the devices like this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f91dWw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Apologies for the poor schematic.

Many thanks,

Comment: I'd say this is exactly the thing you should do.
It rather is problematic to use two powersupplies because they'd need a common ground.

Comment: @Gedobbles any power supply one could reasonably use in this project would tolerate having its ground connected to that of another.  A supply that could not tolerate this - which is to say, an *non-isolated* supply - is not safe to use for this.   If the pi and some other load should or should not share a supply depends both on the capability of that supply, and if that load is "well behaved" or draws (and potentially returns!) power in ways which do "nasty" things to the supply rails - *available* power supplies are not ideal voltage sources, but rather can be impacted by their loads.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine, the current will split at the node and the node voltage shared between the devices will be maintained at 5V by the power supply.

2A will go to the Pi and 4A will go to the LED's.

Make sure you have a good ground, it would be better to run cables right back to the supply like this (than to split them as shown in the diagram in the OP):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh99Je.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A configuration like this will avoid common mode voltage noise caused by changes in current through the wires. Epecially since these are potentially large currents. 50mΩ of wire with 2A would create a 0.1V of voltage through the wire.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your input! Apologies in advance for the rough hand drawing, but does this make sense in terms of wiring/connections? Also, what would be a good real world way of connecting to ground?  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qNe-DV3BQ_LjQM0g-b8db2yAOpy7lwBC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also, to be clear. My intentions are to connect the power supply to the appropriate cables/connectors. A USB cable for the pi and a 2-pin molex connector (unsure of terminology there). But basically this is my intention when it comes to making the connections. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_prdwuYdxMik3HZTlfTcswTitP5C795T/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Instead of making the Y connection in the cable, make it at the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

Your supply is correct for this situation, but don't generalize this.

Your schematic shows the devices as resistive loads; the implication there is that the current drawn is proportional to the voltage input.  That is not the case for either of these devices, and this would not work if it were.

Your devices each have their own power regulation, so that they draw what power they need from a constant input voltage.  Here all you need to consider is the desired input voltage (range) and the maximum current that each may need; your supply matches the voltage requirement and will handle the combined (summed) current requirements of both.  So this is good.

Comment: Great. Thank you !